# Jboss Spring rest Controller and angular2 error parsing

Tags: angular, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, jboss-eap-7

jboss EAP + spring rest controller

My problem is with error response, even though i am throwing exception with error msg client receives html error page from jboss. which do not have my error msg.. so my code fails to parse the error and in result i have to display generic error msg.

Following is my rest controller implementation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<PModel> saveProgram(Authentication authentication, @RequestBody PModel p){


    m = pService.saveP(p, authentication.getName());
    return new ResponseEntity<PModel>(m, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

my pService.save throws an error as following

```
Save(){
…
throw new RuntimeException("ID not found: "+model.id);
}
```

my angular post request as following

```
getP
(p: P):Observable<P>{

    return this.http.post('api/program/types', p, this.prepareHeaderInfo()) // ...using post request
        .map((res:Response) => res.json() as P) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if

}
```

response i receives as error as html as following without my error

```
<html><head><title>JBoss Web/-redhat-1 - JBWEB000064: Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>JBWE: type</b> JBWE: Status report</p><p><b>JBWE: message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>JBWE: description</b> <u>JBWE: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: The endpoint you're showing expects a POST request but you're sending a GET request. Normally that should result in a 405, not a 400

Comment: Try send a POST request `http.post(url, data, headerInfo)`

Comment: sorry my bad its post actually, let me fix the question

Comment: If that's the real method, it still won't work, as you aren't sending any data. How about just copy and pasting the real code, along with the data and how it's populated

Comment: Have you logged `p` to see what it has? can you post that also

Comment: yeah P is plain JSON object response.

Comment: i have made the code changes in above question.  jboss take over status code 400 and send its response html as error page

Comment: `p` from the method argument. The data that is being sent in the request. Have you at least logged it to see that all the data is actually there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127113/discussion-between-faisal-khan-and-peeskillet).